# Postgres COPY command escapes new lines and tabs

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a sql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dump_func()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

r  record;

loc varchar(100);

BEGIN

    for r in (SELECT f.oid as oid, proname, pg_get_functiondef(f.oid) as src
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc f
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (f.pronamespace = n.oid)
            WHERE n.nspname = 'public') loop

        loc = '/Users/raman/Desktop/functions/' || r.proname || '.sql';

        raise notice '% - %', r.oid, loc;
        raise notice 'func: %', r.src;

         EXECUTE format('COPY (
            SELECT pg_get_functiondef(f.oid)
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc f
                INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (f.pronamespace = n.oid)
            WHERE n.nspname = ''public'' and f.oid=%s
            ) TO ''%s'' ', r.oid, loc); 

    end loop;
end
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

which exports each db functions in postgres into a separate file using the COPY command. Everything works except that in the exported sql files new lines and tabs are escaped, for example:

> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.is_numeric(text)\n RETURNS boolean\n
>   LANGUAGE plpgsql\n IMMUTABLE\nAS $function$\nDECLARE x
>   NUMERIC;\nBEGIN\n    x = $1::NUMERIC;\n    RETURN TRUE;\nEXCEPTION
>   WHEN others THEN\n    RETURN FALSE;\nEND;\n$function$\n

As you can see new lines and tabs are escaped, how to fix that?

Comment: default column delimiter in not csv format os tab, and row separator is always new line... You can specify other delimiter, but you still won't be able to get rid of ASCII(10)

Comment: `COPY` is for multiple rows and multiple columns, so there must be separators between rows and columns. These separators may always conflict with arbitrary contents. Consider using client-side `SELECT` into file rather than server-side `COPY`.

Comment: Thanks all for comments, as @Daniel said, it would be more flexible using client-side querying. I guess some ant script would probably solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this can be done. Hacky though it is you simply use `regexp_split_to_table` and split on the `\n` character. I was just trying to work out the same problem myself. Here's the code I wound up with:

```
DO $$

  DECLARE
    v_row record;
    v_proname text;
    v_sql text;

BEGIN

  FOR v_row IN (
    SELECT f.proname
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc AS f
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS n ON (f.pronamespace = n.oid)
    WHERE n.nspname = 'public' AND f.proisagg = false
  ) LOOP

    SELECT v_row.proname::text INTO v_proname;
    EXECUTE FORMAT('COPY (
      SELECT regexp_split_to_table(regexp_replace(pg_get_functiondef(oid), ''\t'', ''   '', ''g''), ''\n'')
      FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc WHERE proname = ''%s'')
      TO ''C:\pg\%s.sql'';'
      , v_proname, v_proname);

  END LOOP;

END $$
```

Answer (score 0):

Andrew's answer is correct, helped me format it as well.

I came up with a similar function but to print all user defined functions in PSQL. Hope it helps to anyone who needs it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION printFunctions(stage VARCHAR, ischema VARCHAR, file_path VARCHAR)
  RETURNS VARCHAR AS
$$
DECLARE
  func VARCHAR;
  file_location TEXT;
BEGIN
  FOR func IN SELECT procname FROM listfunctions()
    LOOP
    SELECT (file_path || '/' || func || '_' || stage || '.sql') INTO file_location;
    IF (SELECT regexp_matches(func, '(pldb|plpg)')) IS NULL
      THEN
        EXECUTE 'COPY ' ||
                '(SELECT regexp_split_to_table(regexp_replace(pg_get_functiondef(oid), ''\t'', ''   '', ''g''),''\n'') from pg_proc where proname=' ||
                '''' || func || '''' ||
                ' and pronamespace=(select oid from pg_namespace where nspname=' ||
                '''' || ischema || ''''
                ')) TO ' || '''' || file_location || '''';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN stage;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

You can call it with:

```
SELECT * FROM printFunctions('dev', 'public', '/tmp');
```